# excel vba - transform an sql

Tags: sql, excel, vba, scripting

Has anyone had any luck with a vba macro that would convert this input:

```
update my_table 
    set time = sysdate, 
    randfield1 = 'FAKE', 
    randfield5 = 'ME', 
    the_field8 = 'test' 
    where my_key = '84' 
    ;
```

into this output?

```
select count(*) from my_table
where (randfield1 <> 'FAKE'
or randfield5 <> 'ME'
or the_field8 <> 'TEST')
and my_key = '84';
```

### update (what happens when using Remou's answer):

INPUT (what i have place in cell A1 of first sheet)-

```
update my_table  
    set time = sysdate,  
    randfield1 = 'FAKE',  
    randfield5 = 'ME',  
    the_field8 = 'test'  
    where my_key = '84'  
    ;
```

OUTPUT (what is generated in a1 of the 2nd sheet once the macro is run)-

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM  my_table
WHERE ()
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
randfield1 <> 'FAKE'
OR )
)
)
)
randfield5 <> 'ME'
OR )
)
)
)
the_field8 <> 'test')
)
)
)
)
AND my_key = '84'
;
```

Comment: Three questions on the same topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515490/excel-vba-macro-extract-value-from-where-clause, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515945/excel-vba-extract-values-from-lines-into-tabular-format and this one?

Comment: @Remou - you can ignore the other qestions but there is a bounty available to sweeten the deal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure what you want, but anyway:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim s As String
Dim c As String
Dim arys As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

''Assuming an existing worksheet
Set r = Sheet1.UsedRange
j = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each cl In r.Cells
    c = cl.Value

    ''Fake spaces
    Do While InStr(c, Chr(160)) > 0
        c = Replace(c, Chr(160), "")
    Loop

    ''Real spaces
    c = Trim(c)

    If c = ";" Then

        arys = Split(s, vbCrLf)

        For i = 0 To UBound(arys)
            Sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = arys(i)
            j = j + 1
        Next

        ''Layout
        j = j + 2

    ElseIf UCase(c) Like "UPDATE*" Then

        s = "SELECT Count(*) FROM " & Replace(c, "update", "", , , vbTextCompare)
        s = s & vbCrLf & "WHERE ("

    ElseIf UCase(c) Like "WHERE*" Then
        s = s & Replace(c, "where", "AND", , , vbTextCompare)
        s = s & vbCrLf & ";"

    ElseIf Left(UCase(c), 3) <> "SET" Then
        c = Replace(c, "=", "<>")

        If Right(c, 1) = "," Then
            s = s & Left(c, Len(c) - 1) & vbCrLf & "OR "
        Else
            s = s & c & ")" & vbCrLf
        End If

    End If
Next
```

Comment: +1 almost there! seems to be adding additional right brackets: )'s. ie OR ).  Also, is adding commas: ,s. Apart from that it matches the desired output mentioned in the question.

Comment: @toop I have corrected the comma, which was an oversight, but I cannot see an extra bracket. What is your input and output?

Comment: Please see my edited question - it has the input and output I'm getting when using your code.

Comment: I have cut and pasted your input into a new Excel document and my macro into a new module and I get nothing like that. It seems you may have unexpected characters in your sheet. Do you have anywhere you can upload your workbook?

Comment: It worked in a new workbook, must have been a problem with the old workbook. Anyway, just before I give you the bounty, can you make it support multiple queries. So if the input was 2 or more queries that the transformation would produce all of them?

Comment: @toop Note that these type of things are very dependent on layout, so they break quite easily.

Comment: has bug if put more/less than 4 fields in the set or more than 1 field in the where.

Comment: @toop, that is not a bug, that is the problem with positional stuff. You need to post more examples, and even at that, it will be limited. You are not going to get an every case scenario here, I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this does at least work for your sample input...

```
Sub NotExtensibleInTheLeast()

  Dim sql As String

  sql = _
      "update my_table " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    set time = sysdate, " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    randfield1 = 'FAKE', " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    randfield5 = 'ME', " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    the_field8 = 'test' " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    where my_key = '84' " & Chr$(10) & _
      "    ;"

  Dim newSql
  newSql = sql
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, "where", ") and")
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, "update", "select count(*) from")
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, "set", "where (")
  newSql = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(newSql, "=", Chr$(22), 5)
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, "=", "<>")
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, Chr$(22), "=")
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, ",", " or ")
  newSql = Replace$(newSql, "time <> sysdate or", vbNullString)

  MsgBox newSql

End Sub
```